# InDesign scripting: How to print specific spot color in separations?

Tags: javascript, printing, adobe-indesign, extendscript

This is my most difficult question to date!  I am still a beginner to ExtendScript & JavaScript, but I am learning fast.  Right now, I need to figure out how to tell InDesign to print specific pages of the active document using a printer preset and—here's the kicker—only using certain spot colors.

Now I have followed both the [Adobe InDesign CS6 JavaScript Scripting Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf) on pages 47–51 as well as [Jongware's guide](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_PrintPreference.html) on the subject.  However, both only refer to turning on or off the Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, and/or Black channels; there is no mention of doing so for any spot colors that exist in the document.

When using the Print dialog normally, you just select the Output tab and click the little printer boxes (basically checkboxes) next to each color that you want printed.  Surely this can be replicated in ExtendScript, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those looking for the answer, [this question was answered on the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5345088).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that earlier; thanks for catching that, dln385!